# How to install and use Sharepoint one Virtual PC from Actual PC instance

Tags: sharepoint, virtualization

Is it possible to install Sharepoint Server on Virtual PC and consume that server from the actual pc instance i.e. connect to the Sharepoint server on the virtual pc instance?

How would I do this, what would be the IP Address for the connection, would it still be 127.0.0.1 even though it is on the Virtual PC?

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this is definately possible. You will need to configure your VPC to allow this though:

- You will need to set the VPC to use Bridged Networking. An exact how-to on this escapes me at the moment, but it's very very important.

Bridged networking will allow your virtual PC to be visible to the rest of the network.

Then, to connect to it, you will use the IP address that the Virtual PC has been assigned by your network DHCP server. If your DHCP server has permissions or restrictions, you will need to get the Virtual PC 'permitted' by it in order to receive an IP address.

E.G. Let's say you've enabled Bridged networking in your VPC, and you've confirmed that you have an IP address for the rest of the network (to confirm this, go to Start > Run > CMD and then when you have the command prompt, type IPCONFIG and look for something like the following):

```
C:\Users\Mark>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


LAN adapter Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1023:f93c:4100:221f%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.163.55
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.163.1
```

The IPv4 address is the one you are looking for. Your connection will be that address (in this case, 192.168.163.55).

Comment: Excellent thanks,  Will give that a try now and get back to you soon. :-)

Comment: Fantastic, Vista automatically detected it, no messing!  Cheers for the advice!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Your Virtual PC will use bridged networking, where it will share the network card with the physical host, but get its own IP address. If you're on a network which uses DHCP to supply clients with IP addresses you will notice that your virtual pc gets its own IP adress, and you can use that to access your sharepoint site.